# Segmentation Fault 11 but why?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a problem in my code but I don't know why I get the segmentation fault 11. The error happens in line

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "VectorMath.h"

int getUserInput() {
  int userinput;

  printf("1) Calculating new vector and distance \n");
  printf("0) Exit \n");

  scanf("%d", &userinput);

  return userinput;
}

void getUserPoint(int vector[3]) {
  int userinput;
  char coordinate[] = {'x', 'y', 'z'};
  int counter = 0;

  for(counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++){
      printf("%c", coordinate[counter]);
      scanf("%d", &userinput);
      vector[counter] = userinput;
  }
}


int main() {
  int vectorA[3];
  int vectorB[3];

  int input = 0;
  int counter = 0;

  int *p_result;

  double result;

  _Bool run = 1;

  while(run) {
      input = getUserInput();

      if (input == 1){
          printf("Enter point A (x,y,z) \n");
          getUserPoint(vectorA);
          printf("Enter point B (x,y,z) \n");
          getUserPoint(vectorB);
      }else if(input == 0) {
          break;
      }

      result = distance(vectorA, vectorB, p_result);

      printf("The distance between the points A and B is %.2lf \n", result);
      printf("The vector between the point A and B is \n");
      for (counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++){
          printf("%d \n", p_result[counter]);
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is the main Methode. The error occurs after (or inside) the for loop. The pointer gets initialized in this .c file:

```
#include "VectorMath.h"
#include <math.h>

double distance(int pointA[3], int pointB[3], int *p_result) {
  double distance_result;
  int vectorbtw[3];
  int counter = 0;

  for(counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
      vectorbtw[counter] = pointB[counter] - pointA[counter];
  }

  p_result = vectorbtw;

  for(counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
      distance_result += pow(vectorbtw[counter], 2);
  }

  distance_result = sqrt(distance_result);

  return distance_result;
}
```

And this is the headder:

```
#ifndef VectorMath_h
#define VectorMath_h
  double distance(int pointA[3], int pointB[3], int *p_result);
#endif
```

Sorry for the long code but I thought you will need the whole code.
As I said I don't know why it happens so the p_result pointer gets initialized in the other .c file and he points to the start of the array.

**EDIT** : I should say that the purpose of this is that I have a function which calculate the distance between 2 points and return the distance AND the vector between the two points. and thats why im doing that with the p_result pointer .

Comment: `p_result` isn't modified by your routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't initialize `int *p_result;` anywhere.  You're passing in the value of an unitialized pointer to your distance routine.  That local copy is set to point at a local array, but after that function call the `p_result` in your main function is still uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

The `p_result` pointer needs to point to valid memory, for example an array, so instead of

```
int *p_result;
```

use

```
int p_result[3];
```

and leave the rest unchanged, did it work?

Your `distance()` function assumes that `p_result` is already a valid pointer, but for that to be true it needs to point somewhere. As it is, it's not pointing anywhere because it's never initialized, you can also do it like this

```
int result[3];
int *p_result;

p_result = result;
```

I hope now you see the point this way.

Comment: I solved the segmentation fault but I gives me just zeros but you and https://stackoverflow.com/users/1813336/cleblanc answered my question thanks.